How to prevent opentelemtry collector running as daemonset scrapping duplicate metrics
I have open telemetry collector running as daemonset in k8s cluster. The cluster has following Prometheus Receiver configuration.
config:
        scrape_configs:
          - job_name: 'otel-node-exporter'
            scrape_interval: 20s
            honor_labels: true
            static_configs:
              - targets: ['${K8S_NODE_IP}:9100']
          - job_name: 'kube-state-metrics'
            scrape_interval: 60s
            static_configs:
              - targets: ['kube-state-metrics.otel.svc.cluster.local:8080']
            relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
                action: replace
                target_label: namespace
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
                action: replace
                target_label: pod_name
            metric_relabel_configs:
              - target_label: cluster
                replacement: eqa-integration
          - job_name: 'kubernetes-pods'
            scrape_interval: 20s
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
              - role: pod
            relabel_configs:
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape]
                action: keep
                regex: true
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_path]
                action: replace
                target_label: __metrics_path__
                regex: (.+)
              - source_labels: [__address__, __meta_kubernetes_pod_annotation_prometheus_io_port]
                action: replace
                regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
                replacement: $${1}:$${2}
                target_label: __address__
              - action: labelmap
                regex: __meta_kubernetes_pod_label_(.+)
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_namespace]
                action: replace
                target_label: kubernetes_namespace
              - source_labels: [__meta_kubernetes_pod_name]
                action: replace
                target_label: kubernetes_pod_name

Now What i can see for job- kube-state-metrics multiple collectors are scrapping. I failed to collect the data for job kubernetes-pods, does each collector pod, scraps from all applications with true annotation? Or does kubernetes_sd_configs:   - role: pod ensures only applocation pod from same nodes are scrapped?

Consider to ask sys-admin questions (e.g. configuration of pre-made software) on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.
